# Android Studio Failed to resolve: support-core-utils

Tags: android, gradle, build

After upgrading support library version to 27.1.1 when i sync the project i face with below error:

```
Failed to resolve: support-core-utils
```

Any idea?

here is my project level build file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and app level build file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Do you have the `google()` repository listed in your `repositories` closures in your top-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes i have

Comment: Can you add the gradle line of the support lib?

Comment: @UrielFrankel added to op

Comment: This is weird... `support-core-utils` is a dependency of `support-v4:` and `appcompat-v7`... You may try `implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1'` to see if it unlocks your situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my case , it was because of a library dependency and I solved by excluding support-core-utils from that library :

```
implementation ('com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-core-utils'
}
```

Comment: I think the top answer is better, to change the order of the repository in the general Gradle config.

Answer (score 87):

I solved this by setting 
google() as first entry in allprojects/repositories in top level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Future readers, note the `as first entry`. `google()` must come before `jcenter()`.

Comment: Superb... found

Answer (score 34):

as per behavior changes in android-Gradle plugin (v3.2.0 September 2018) you need to keep the google repository as the first entry

```
buildscript {
      repositories {
          google() // here
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
      }
  }
  allprojects {
      repositories {
          google() // and here
          jcenter()
  }
```

[android-Gradle plugin release note](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Comment: unbelievable. it works. i could not understand why cant they maintain backward compat, instead of breaking thousands of builds. thank god, we have SO.

Answer (score 11):

I have same problem and i changed to successful.
Added maven `{ url 'https://maven.google.com' }` as first entry in allprojects/repositories in top level `build.gradle`

Comment: It's already present for OP though. `google()` is the Google repo

Comment: any progress for this issue? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Changing the order did work for me. Any explanation?

Comment: It did work for me also, thank you for this answer. And shame on gradle for this nonsense bug.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with `AppCompat` library with version `28.0.0`. I fixed it by using `28.0.0-alpha1`. **None** of answers helped me. 
Android studio 3.1.4
Target and compile sdk **28**.

At the time the library was not really stable. `support-core-utils` is a part of `android-support-v4`, so if you still have a problem with that try adding 
`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'` 
to the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

do you add implementation 'com.android.support:design:XX.X.X', implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:XX.X.X' ?
when I saw "duplicate value for resource" message I just had implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

and I added **implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'**

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' and worked it !

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mavenCentral()` from repositories script in project level if there.